# Mutivariate function having sequential limit but not ordinary limit

Tags: limits, functions

> Given a multivariate function $f(x,y)$. Can it have sequential limits but not ordinary limit?

Have taken $f(x,y)=\frac{x-4y}{6y+7x}$.  For it the sequential limits are:

$\lim_{y \to 0} \hspace{1mm} \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \hspace{1mm} \frac{x-4y}{6y+7x} \right)$ which is existing and is equal to -2/3.

$\lim_{x \to 0} \hspace{1mm} \left( \lim_{y \to 0} \hspace{1mm} \frac{x-4y}{6y+7x} \right)$ which is existing and is equal to 1/7.

However, the ordinary limit i.e.

$\lim_{\left (x,y \right ) \to \left (0,0 \right )} \hspace{1mm} \frac{x-4y}{6y+7x}$ does not exist as when we try to plug values $\left (x,0 \right )$ and $\left (y,0 \right )$ to it, the limit values are different.

Thus the sequential limits of $f(x,y)$ are existing but the ordinary limit of it does not exist.

Can you please let me know if the approach is correct for the above formulation?

Comment: What you did makes sense. However, I'm not sure that *sequential limits* is a proper math terminology. It seems that [iterated limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit) is more usual. As English is not my first language, a confirmation on that matter is welcomed!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thank you. yes i guess it should be iterated limits.